# Is it possible to get client ip in setting.php

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm trying to get the client IP in settings.php for security reasons, using the following code.
I have to support `X-Forwarded-For` header because accessing web server over loadbalancer.

```
$clientIp = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
```

It causes the following error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container. in Drupal::getContainer() (line 129 of /var/www/my-site/docroot/core/lib/Drupal.php).
>       Drupal::getContainer() (Line: 218)
>       Drupal::request() (Line: 759)
>       require('/var/www/my-site/docroot/sites/default/settings.php') (Line: 116)
>       Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::initialize('/var/www/my-site/docroot', 'sites/default', Object) (Line: 1015)
>       Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeSettings(Object) (Line: 642)
>       Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: "For security reasons" - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want restrict access by ip on Acquia cloud with this method. https://gist.github.com/acquialibrary/9553136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.php` the drupal kernel is not loaded yet, so the service container is not initialized. Use the php superglobal `$_SERVER`instead:

```
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: This is unreliable in itself .